# Can we recover the azure resource group in azure cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

Some times we had deleted the 'resource group' accidentally on azure cloud, its fine that if our/your resource group does not have any deployments on it and we can create immediately newer one and will proceed our stuff, but if we had deployments on it, then its becomes major problem/task.

So can we recover Resource Group? like a recovery of Virtual machine in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can export service configurations that belong to a resource group as JSON. Within the portal, there is an option "Export Template" under the Resource Management Navigation Group.

Answer (score 0):

> So can we recover Resource Group? like a recovery of Virtual machine in Azure.

Unfortunately, we have no way to recovery it, if the resource group is deleted .  We could get the warning if we try to delete resource group from the azure portal.  Connect to Azure support team for help maybe a way, but I don't think it could be easy for restoring.

[image]

**Note** : based on my understanding even if we could re-create the resource with ARM template(`If we have exported the ARM template before delete`), it seems that just with the same resource names with deleted resource that is not equal recovery action.